# MySQL NDB Cluster Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

When creating table or inserting data into one node of MySQL cluster using the NDB engine, it is always propagated to the other nodes in the cluster, but when I add a stored procedure, I have to manually create it in all nodes.

Is there something I can do to have the stored procedure propagated to all nodes in the cluster when it is only created in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> Stored routines and triggers in MySQL Cluster.
>
> Stored procedures,
>   stored functions, and triggers are all supported by tables using the
>   NDB storage engine; however, it is important to keep in mind that they
>   do not propagate automatically between MySQL Servers acting as Cluster
>   SQL nodes. This is because of the following:
>
> Stored routine definitions are kept in tables in the mysql system
>   database using the MyISAM storage engine, and so do not participate in
>   clustering.
>
> The .TRN and .TRG files containing trigger definitions are not read by
>   the NDB storage engine, and are not copied between Cluster nodes.
>
> Any stored routine or trigger that interacts with MySQL Cluster tables
>   must be re-created by running the appropriate CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE
>   FUNCTION, or CREATE TRIGGER statements on each MySQL Server that
>   participates in the cluster where you wish to use the stored routine
>   or trigger. Similarly, any changes to existing stored routines or
>   triggers must be carried out explicitly on all Cluster SQL nodes,
>   using the appropriate ALTER or DROP statements on each MySQL Server
>   accessing the cluster.